# ASP.net Drop Down List Populating More Than Once on Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, refresh, state

I'm sorry for the trivial question, but I cannot find info about this on Google, or in my reference books, which accurately describes/solves my problem.

I have some DropDownList controls on a page, that I am populating with info from a SQL table.  When the page is refreshed, the DropDownLists don't lose their old values, but instead get the same values added to them all over again, so now they are double populated.  The functionality all still works the same, but it makes the DropDownList controls look less neat and obviously is unwanted.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" OnLoad="LoadDutchessSubjects"
            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

The LoadDutchessSubjects function in my code behind just grabs all records from the SQL table and loads them into the DDL:

```
public void LoadDutchessSubjects(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = SqlHelperClass.ConnectionString;
    DataTable subjects = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM cfhudson_counties ORDER BY County", con);
            adapter.Fill(subjects);
            DropDownList2.DataSource = subjects;
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "County";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "County";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<ERROR: Occured in populating.>", "1"));
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    //Overall.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Select Subject>", "0")); //(dev test)
}
```

Is there something I can do in the Code Behind to prevent this from happening?  Does this have to do with ASP.net state and refreshing/what's going on server side?  Maybe we can turn this question into a more useful and general explanation of why this is happening in the first place, because  I evidently don't understand some important thing about ASP.net here.

Comment: How do you refresh the page? with a postback?

Comment: I guess I don't really know what a postback really is.  I am refreshing the page when the user clicks on an ASP.net button on the page, which runs another function which brings back data to load onto the page.  I can post that as well if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not reload the items on postbacks. they are persisted in viewstate

```
public void LoadDutchessSubjects(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostback)
        return;

    string connectionString = SqlHelperClass.ConnectionString;
    DataTable subjects = new DataTable();
```

Comment: Will study thank you very much.  I'm sure this is really the problem, which is more of my lack of understanding of the ASP.net lifecycle/postbacks.